# Extracting line coordinates with Leaflet and VectorGrid

Tags: leaflet, vector-grid

I'm using a map display in Leaflet and polylines using Leaflet.VectorGrid.

By clicking on a line I want to export the coordinates of this line.

```
var layerGroup12 = L.vectorGrid.slicer( pistes,{
  rendererFactory: L.svg.tile,
  vectorTileLayerStyles: {
    sliced: 
    
    function(properties, zoom){
             var level = map.getZoom();
            
            if (level >= 10) {
            return {
                weight: 3,
                color: "#22e608",
                stroke: true,
                opacity: 1
}
            } else
            {
            return {
                         weight: 1,
                         color: "#22e608",
                         opacity: 1,
                         stroke: true,              
            }
            }   
    }
                      
},
  maxZoom: 20,
  indexMaxZoom: 5,
  interactive: true,
  pane: "pane500",
  getFeatureId: function(f) {
            return f.properties.name;
} 
})
.on('click', function(e) {
            var properties = e.layer.properties;
            L.popup()
                .setContent(properties.name || properties.type)
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .openOn(map);
            clearHighlight();
        highlight = properties.name;

    
        
        var style = {
                stroke: true,
                color: 'magenta',
                opacity: 1,
                weight: 4,
            };

// Lines added to try to get the coordinates

var coords = e.layer.getLatLngs();

console.log(coords);

layerGroup12.setFeatureStyle(properties.name, style);

})
```

On click, "console.log" return "undefined"

What is the correct syntax for extracting these coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector grid layer knows nothing about individual feature coordinates of features from which it was constructed (sliced), so `.getLatLngs()` is not implemented.

Since you are constructing vector grid layer on the fly from GeoJSON, solution is to get coordinates from original GeoJSON `pistes` one the basis of `f.properties.name` property used for `getFeatureId` option.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
.on('click', function(e) {
  var properties = e.layer.properties;
  L.popup()
    .setContent(properties.name || properties.type)
    .setLatLng(e.latlng)
    .openOn(map);
    clearHighlight();
  highlight = properties.name;

  var style = {
    stroke: true,
    color: 'magenta',
    opacity: 1,
    weight: 4,
  };
  layerGroup12.setFeatureStyle(properties.name, style);

  var feature = pistes.features.find(function(feature) {
    return(feature.properties.name == properties.name);
  });
  var coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;
  console.log(coords);
}
```